# View images in GridView from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

i have a grid view from three columns , on it i need only to make photo gallery that i bring images from database

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="200px" Height="200px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("imageUrl")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=BASSAM-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=fame;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=root" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [imageURL] FROM [studentNew] WHERE ([type] = @type)">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="gallary" Name="type" Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

the problem is the same photo appear three times in the columns i want it to change one by one in each column 
how i can do that ??

Comment: It appears 3 times because you have a template for it three times.  What are you trying to do? `I want to change one by one in each column` makes no sense to me.

Comment: what i want for exmple : i have 9 pictures and i want to show them in the grid view , each three of them on one row
my code let the same picture come three times and get 9 rows
i want them to be only three rows each row have three items

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , change to use list item instead of grid view

```
<asp:ListView ID="ImageListView" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder" GroupPlaceholderID="groupPlaceHolder" OnItemCommand="ImageListView_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <h1>
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="titleLabel" OnLoad="titleLabel_Load" />
        </h1>
        <div runat="server" id="groupPlaceHolder">
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <span>
            <div id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></div>
        </span>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="itemImageButton" runat="server"
            CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>"
            ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Width="320" Height="240"
            OnCommand="itemImageButton_Command" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteLinkButton" runat="server" CommandName="Remove"
            CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" Text="Delete" Visible="false"
            OnLoad="deleteLinkButton_Load" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>
        <td />
    </EmptyItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <h3>No images available</h3>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <asp:Label Text="Please upload an image" runat="server" ID="imageUploadLabel" />
            <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="imageUpload" OnLoad="imageUpload_Load" />
            <asp:Button ID="uploadButton" Text="Upload" runat="server" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="imageUploadStatusLabel" />
        </p>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and all code in the code behind file

for more detail you can the below link 
[create an image grid](http://geekswithblogs.net/omtalsania7/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-create-an-image-grid-with-asp.net-44.5-using.aspx)